# How did Satyavati die and how old was she at the time?

Tags: mahabharata, vyasa

I read somewhere on this site that Bhishma's age was around 140 years when he died. But Satyavati was his mother, so, she must have been ~160 years old if she was alive when Bhishma died (I could be wrong here).

Also, I saw in Star Plus Mahabharat ([here](https://www.hotstar.com/tv/mahabharat/s-28/pandavas-ordered-to-wage-war/1000011975) S20E10) that Vyasa tells Satyavati to die because she won't be able to bear the darkness of future after the war.

If that's true, it means she could have lived even longer. Maybe 200 years? Was living 200 years possible at that time? What's the truth?

Comment: I don't think Bhishma and vyasa tags are relevant. Just MB tag is fine

Comment: @KrishnaShweta edited it.

Comment: But what are non fiction and non mythology? Keep MB only

Comment: @KrishnaShweta some people here believe Mahabharata and events are a fiction.

Comment: Hmm but leave about it. These tags are not correct. Keep MB only.

Comment: Hello Vikas. Tags do not indicate beliefs of people. If such tags are added, it creates a mess. When people are tagging mythology, it doesn't we as a site are naming it as false. Tags indicate the topic of the question only. Another suggestion, don't rely too much on Starplus mahabharata. There is a lot of creative license taken by author.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma thanks but non-fiction is necessary. It's my Dharma to put it.

Comment: @Vikas It's not needed. It indicates personal belief of a user. There is no Dharma or Adharma on this site. Just some SE etiquette on tagging and Code of Conduct. :)

Comment: But people won't understand then @Sarvabhouma they will post false answers. Let me tell you. Once a user answered something like: "Avatars in Mahabharata is false". And that ruined my all trust. Dharma does exist.

Comment: Vikas.. if answers are wrong we can flag them and they will be deleted. Everyone has their own beliefs that's why we ask for references in answers. Even if you keep "non fiction" we cannot assure that there won't be those kind of answers. You know MB itself is great name for us. So chill

Comment: 'Vyasa tells Satyavati to die' - you mean commit suicide?! Which episode is this? Better to add link to Hotstar video so people understand the context. Also, your title question is different from what you ask in the body about human lifespan.

Comment: Also, see [How could octogenarian heroes fight in Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/how-could-octogenarian-heroes-fight-in-mahabharata)

Comment: @sv. I don't doubt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After death of Pandu, Vyasa advised Satyavati to retire into the forest and engage in the contemplation through Yoga.

On this advice, Satyavati retired to forest where she left her body:

> Acquiescing in the words of Vyasa, Satyavati entered the inner apartments and addressed her daughter-in-law, saying, 'O Ambika, I hear that in consequence of the deeds of your grandsons, this Bharata dynasty and its subjects will perish. If thou permit, I would go to the forest with Kausalya, so grieved at the loss of her son.' O king, saying this the queen, taking the permission of Bhishma also, went to the forest. And arriving there with her two daughters-in-law, she became engaged in profound contemplation, and in good time leaving her body ascended to heaven.'
>
> ~[Mahaabhaarata: Aadi Parva: Sambhava Parva: SECTION CXXVIII](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01129.htm)

---

> But Satyavati was his mother, so, she must have been ~160 years old if she was alive when Bhishma died

It's not necessary that Satyavati's age has to be more than that of Bhishma as she was not biological mother of Bhishma. When she married to Santanu, Bhishma was already of matured age. So, she was more or less of the same age of Bhishma. As she died after Pandu's death when Pandvas were infants, so she would be in her sixties or seventies [ **140** (Bhishma's age in Mahabharata war) - **91** (Yudhisthira's age in Mahabharata war)  + **16** (Yudhisthira's age when Pandu died) + **Y** (years she spent in forest) ].

---

Related

[What were the ages of Pandavas & other characters during the Mahabharata war?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5170/what-were-the-ages-of-pandavas-other-characters-during-the-mahabharata-war/5177#5177)

Comment: Can anyone tell me Viduraji how much long lived on this earth? Actually he was Dharma Raj according Chapter 65,Aadi Parva, Mahabharata.

Comment: @user17854 u can ask this in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32873/how-did-vidura-die-in-the-mahabharata?r=SearchResults

Comment: Dhanyavad (θ‿θ)

Comment: I am assuming while accepting this answer that, Satyavati was Shantanu's 2nd wife. First was Ganga.

Comment: @Vikas "Satyavati was Shantanu's 2nd wife. First was Ganga"-- yes, true..

Comment: Bhishma and Satyavati were of same age probably . when did bhishma die huh? he just goes to Vasu loka.

Comment: Bhishma and Satyavati were of same age probably . when did bhishma die huh? he just goes to Vasu loka. Bhishma was greatest warrior decides to  be on arrow bed and goes to Vasu Loka without no death. Bhishma was gallant. Satyavati did die I think