# Significance of stones in mouth: An intriguing aspect of Vidura's final state in the Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, sadhana, vidura

In the Mahabharata, the state of Vidura just prior to [his departure](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32873/how-did-vidura-die-in-the-mahabharata) is vividly described. Here's the excerpt

> He had matted locks on his head, and **gravels in his mouth**, and was
> exceedingly emaciated. He was perfectly naked. His body was besmeared
> all over with filth, and with the dust of various wild flowers.
>
> [[Section 26, Asramavasa Parva, Asramavasika Parva, The
> Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m15/m15026.htm)

The part that particularly piqued my interest is the mention of Vidura having gravels in his mouth. Is it possible that the presence of these rocks could be part of a  sadhana? If so, could anyone provide the name of this specific sadhana and elaborate on its purpose or significance in the context of Hindu texts?